# access SQL Server 2008 from PHP 5.3.6 and apache

Tags: php, sql-server

I struggle for a few days now to install xampp and run testlink 1.9.2 but using a SQL Server database. the problem is that php 5.3 does not use php_mssql.dll and it doesn't even let me use the older one either. someone mentioned I could use jtds, but I do not need, want or have java installed on that server.

Answer (score 0):

About win-bin
PHP 5.3.6 from php-5.3.6-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip (php-5.3.6-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.msi - see php dot com) not support MSSQL.

phpinfo():
Configure Command 
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet" "--with-mcrypt=static"

"--without-mssql"

### "--without-pdo-mssql"

PHP 5.2.17 (php-5.2.17-nts-Win32-VC6-x86.zip) work with MSSQL.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the SQL Server Driver for PHP, as offered by microsoft. It will provide your PHP environment with a robust connector to SQL Server, offering a multitude of features.

Read more details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/ and http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/

Comment: hi cairnz, can you provide me with a link to a tutorial on how to install...actually with this I lost my time the last couple of days and could not make it work

Comment: It should be enough to put the php5srv_xx.dl into your extension folder and add it to php.ini - you can use a test page showing `<?phpinfo()?>` to verify it's been loaded correctly. This page should cover it in more detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296203.aspx

Comment: System requirements listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx